# JSON обработка данных вывод в HTML

Tags: javascript, json, vkontakte-api

Решил попробовать поработать с VK_API не зная JS, JSON, JQuery.

Проблема в том что сервер отдаёт данные в JSON, но обработать их не как не получается, почитал пару гайдов, но не один не сработал в моих руках.

```js
$('#load').on('click', loadFriends);
$('#load1').on('click', loadJson);

function getUrl(method, params) {
  params['access_token'] = '';
  return 'https://api.vk.com/method/' + 'friend.search' + '?' + $.param(params) + '&v=5.72';
}

function sendRequest(method, params, func) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.search?count=60&fields=photo_100&access_token=&v=5.72',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}

function loadFriends() {
  sendRequest('friends.search', {
    count: 60,
    fields: 'photo_100'
  }, function(data) {
    drawFriends(data.response);
  });

}

function drawFriends(friends) {
  var html = '';

  var f = friends[i];
  html += +'<h4>' + f.first_name + '</h4>';

  alert(data.response.item[1].first_name);
  html += +'<h4>' + cart.item[1].first_name + '</h4>';
}


function loadJson() {

  var cart = JSON.parse(data);

  alert(cart.item[1].first_name);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="load">Показать друзей</button>
<button id="load1">Показать друзей1</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что нужно сделать?

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос? Что не получилось конкретно?

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Вывести допустим имя пользователя, или ID, просто понять хочу как выводить что либо из JSONa

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev Вообще нечего не получилось, нечего не выводится в HTML

Comment: console.log(data[0]['id']);

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Куда именно? Где это написать? Чтоб вывелось в HTML?

Comment: success: function(data) {
                console.log(data[0]['id']);
            }

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Не получилось, выдаёт ошибку, в консоль нечего не вывелось, в HTML тоже нечего не вывелось.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: при клике на #load1 выводит Json, так же?

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Это я тестил на кнопку #load1, а сейчас пытался в #load просто запихнуть, где success в ajax, попытался в #load1 в функцию loadJson, но там сразу web storm заругался.

Comment: `var cart = JSON.parse(data);` эта строчка парсит  json в массив

Comment: тогда стоит в теле функции `success` вызывать `loadJson(data)`

Comment: @AlexandrMaliovaniy Ошибка "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#load').on('click', loadFriends);

function getUrl(method, params) {
  params['access_token'] = '';
  return 'https://api.vk.com/method/' + 'friend.search' + '?' + $.param(params) + '&v=5.72';
}

function sendRequest(method, params, func) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.search?count=60&fields=photo_100&access_token=&v=5.72',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success: function(data) {
      loadJson(data);
    }
  });
}

function loadFriends() {
  sendRequest('friends.search', {
    count: 60,
    fields: 'photo_100'
  }, function(data) {
    drawFriends(data.response);
  });

}

function drawFriends(friends) {
  var html = '';

  var f = friends[i];
  html += +'<h4>' + f.first_name + '</h4>';

  alert(data.response.item[1].first_name);
  html += +'<h4>' + cart.item[1].first_name + '</h4>';
}


function loadJson(data) {

  var cart = JSON.parse(data);

  alert(cart.item[1].first_name);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="load">Показать друзей</button>
```

Comment: Ошибка "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Comment: Исправил, `loadJson` не принимал `data`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сдвинулся с мёртвой точки, теперь новая ошибка :D

Comment: VM2636:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at loadJson (index.html?_ijt=efh095akncfvrneb2mtvm4ie4k:50)
    at Object.success (index.html?_ijt=efh095akncfvrneb2mtvm4ie4k:26)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: закоментируйте тело `loadJson` и добавте `console.log(typeof(data));`

Comment: Malinovaniy Вообщем получилось что всё заработало, в консоль теперь выводится "Объект" но не какой больше информации, как быть дальше?

Comment: а, ну так `data` уже объект, тоесть парсить не нужно (удалите сторчку `var cart = JSON.parse(data);`